# How to reapply new text format in CSS after removing format initially

Tags: html, css

Currently having a slight problem with regards to getting my text to appear in a certain way:

I currently have the following:

```
%><DIV class="quote status">&nbsp;<b>status:&nbsp;</b><%=o.getStatus()%><%
```

Which returns the following text:

> **status**:CONFIRMED

I have applied the following CSS to remove the uppercase format:

```
.quote.status{
    text-transform: lowercase;
    float: right;
}
```

which returns this:

> **status**:confirmed

However i am unsure how to achieve the following:

> **Status**:Confirmed

using CSS.

Any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used `capitalize` for that:

> text-transform: capitalize; /* For First character of each word to uppercase */
>
> text-transform: lowercase; /* For lowercase */
>
> text-transform: uppercase; /* For uppercase */

```css
.quote.status{
    text-transform: capitalize;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote status">&nbsp;<b>status:&nbsp;</b><%=o.getStatus()%></div>
<br/>
<div class="quote status">&nbsp;<b>status:&nbsp;</b> confirmed</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the value 'capitalize' for text-transform and also the selector :first-letter and put a

tag surrounding your server response.

```css
p{
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

p:first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<p>CONFIRMED</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `text-transform: capitalize;`

This transforms the first character of each word to uppercase.